# understanding involute and evolute .

Tags: differential-geometry

I have a bit confusion about the properties of centre of circular curvature . Is there any difference between locus  of centres of circle of curvature and involute ?

Comment: nobody has yet given the answer to this question .. it shouldn't be too tough ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after spending too time in this problem what i find is that , by definition involute lies in the tangent plane of  a  given curve and the curve traced by the locus of center of circle curvature does not necessarily lie in the tangent plane . also the tangent to a given curve is normal to involute while as the tangent to curve traced by center of curvature lies in normal plane of given curve .